# JQuery Add Hidden HTML Elements

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='Show Picture' id='add'><div class='input'style='display: none;'><img src="http://www.myimg.com/img.png"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
$(".input:hidden:first").show() });
```

Basically when I press the Show Picture button, the hidden picture appears below. 
Now how can I make it so that if I click the button again, the image disappears. And it does so continuously. (clickbutton -> show image; clickbutton -> hide image; click button -> show image...)

Thanks!

Comment: toggle(); http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try toggle : [Further reading](http://learn.jquery.com/effects/intro-to-effects/)

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".input:first").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Is there also a way to continuously add the image below every time the button is clicked?

Comment: @Overflow Add this line in the onclick $('.input>img:first').clone().appendTo('.input'); to add a copy of the image to the div every time you click the button.

Answer (score 4):

Use `toggle()` or the related methods:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".input:first").toggle();
    // or: $(".input:first").fadeToggle();
    // or: $(".input:first").slideToggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo: `toggle()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Jp4pq/).

[JS Fiddle demo: `fadeToggle()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Jp4pq/1/).

[JS Fiddle demo: `slideToggle()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Jp4pq/2/).

References:

- [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).
- [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Is there also a way to continuously add the image below every time the button is clicked?

Comment: You want to...click the button three times and have three copies of the same image?

Comment: Exactly, any number of times though, without having to hide html for each image.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cnt=1;
$("#add").click(function() {
if(cnt)
{
$(".input:hidden:first").show() 
cnt=0;
}
else{
$(".input:hidden:first").hide() 
cnt=1;
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  $(".input:hidden:first").toggle(); 
});
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) here

```
 $("#add").click(function() {
    $(".input:hidden:first").toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#add").on('click',function() {

     $(".input:hidden").toggle();
   });
```