# Part 2: JQuery Add Hidden HTML Elements

Tags: jquery, html

A follow up to what I had posted in this thread:

[JQuery Add Hidden HTML Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120938/jquery-add-hidden-html-elements)

```
<input type='button' value='Show Picture' id='add'>
<div class='input'style='display: none;'>
<div class="form" id="inter"></div>
```

This is what works for me. When I press the button, the image appears.

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".input:hidden:first").toggle()
});
```

**But** another part of my JQuery removes the div when I press on it. (as I had intended it to do).

The problem is, when I press the the button once more, the image doesn't reapear. 
I want it to work like an endless cycle. I show the image, click on it to dismiss it, click the button and the image is shown once again.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/7KGEu/

Answer (score 0):

I believe something very similar to your first answer should work.  Please try this:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  $(".form").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Each one of my divs has both a class and an id, (ex: div class = "form" id = "inter" ) What you did was what I wanted but I also need the id. How could I do that?

@Frog I tried that but it didn't seem to work. Maybe because I forgot to mention the id?

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are appending div every time you click on button what you do is replace the content of div.

```
<input type='button' value='Show Picture' id='add'>
<div class='input'>
    <div class="form" style="display:none;">Somgthing here</div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
 $("#add").click(function() {
  $('#container').html($('.input').html()).find('.form').show();
 });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jp4pq/16/

check it.