# JQuery toggle show and dismiss

Tags: jquery, html

A follow up to what I had posted in this thread:

[JQuery Add Hidden HTML Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120938/jquery-add-hidden-html-elements)

**HERE IS THE FIDDLE CONTAINING ALL RELEVANT INFORMATION:** http://jsfiddle.net/3YGJP/2/

```
<input type='button' value='Show Picture' id='add'>
<div class='input'style='display: none;'>
<div class="form" id="inter">"other divs for more content"<div class="xbutton">x</div></div>
```

This is what works for me (When I press the button, the content in the div appears):

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".input:first").toggle()
});
```

But another part of my JQuery removes the div when I press on it. (as I had intended it to do).

The problem is, when I press the the button once more, the content in the div doesn't reappear. I want it to work like an endless cycle. I click the button "Show Form" and the content in the div appears, I click the content and the content is now hidden then I click the button once more and the content is shown again....and etc...\

And here is the JQuery that closes my div:

```
$('.xbutton').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
```

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are removing you element. It will be completely deleted and you can't get it back. Why not also toggle it when you want to 'delete' it?

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".input:hidden:first").toggle()
});

$('.xbutton').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().toggle();
});
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YGJP/1/)

## Update

You are actually not hiding your `.input` element with the hide function. But you are hiding the `.form` element. So you should add one more parent selector:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

To make this simpler you can use:

```
$(this).parents('.input').hide();
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YGJP/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple, you need to use delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function() {
    $(".input:hidden:first").toggle()
});
```

Comment: That worked well too. Don't see why anyone would downvote. The only problem is, it still doesn't reappear and works like the code suggested in the previous thread. I posted the JQuery that dismisses my div, so I hope that it will clarify things.

Comment: Sure let me add it to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Works Fine...

```
$("#add").click(function() {
      $(".input:first").toggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MNnQK/)